# Time missing from panel

Tags: indicator

How to get the time back in the systray? I had it in the middle of the toolbar at the top of classic 11.04 but upgraded to ubuntu 11.10 and it is gone. I have set whitelist to "all" already.

Answer (score 4):

If you're running Unity, not Gnome Shell, my guess is that indicator-datetime isn't running. Try running `/usr/lib/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-service` from a terminal window. Hopefully that'll fix things. If not, please edit your question to include the exact error message(s) you received.

To launch a terminal, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. You can also type this command to get a list of indicators that are currently running:

```
ps -ef | grep [i]ndicator
```

Comment: I did a little cleaning with synaptic (oops) and I lost my clock/calendar and do not how to get it back. I ran /usr/lib/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-service but it just came back as: bash: /usr/lib/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-service: No such file or directory
know what I need to install to get it back? Thanks

Comment: @Dustin: You can find which package is responsible for a file via `dpkg --search filename`. In this case, ensure that `indicator-datetime` is installed.

Comment: On 14.04 I had to run: "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-service &"

Answer (score 3):

To get it back if it is missing or accidentally uninstalled just add it:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime
```

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 13.10, run `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-datetime-service` in terminal can be a solution.

TIPS: Use `ps -ef | grep [i]ndicator` to find the indicators' location.

Answer (score 1):

This did it for me:

```
pkill -f datetime
```

Edit: Kills the process that displays time. Ubuntu will probably then restart the process.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain what this command does, and why you believe it to be a solution.

Comment: This answer works for me when my time goes missing from the toolbar.