# Missing Date and Time from top panel on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, indicator

I recently upgraded my system to Ubuntu 16.04 but after the up gradation I notice the date and time widget has disappeared from the top panel.

I tried the commands sudo killall unity-panel-service but didn't work. I Re-installed it but that too didn't work

I tried setting it on GUI on but the clock tab in Time & Date appears dead. [Clock screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIfmP.png)

It would really nice if someone could help me with it.

Comment: Maybe this will help : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TimeAndDate

Comment: I tried that. But it doesn't work

Comment: RELATED:http://askubuntu.com/questions/72671/time-missing-from-panel?rq=1

Comment: RELATED:http://askubuntu.com/questions/45970/missing-date-time-applet-from-top-unity-panel?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Can you give more details about the steps that you followed to try to solve the problem? @sameermohanty

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the solutions suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/522557/date-and-time-settings-gui-in-ubuntu-14-04-is-not-working).

I faced the same problem, and `pkill -f indicator-datetime-service` fixed my issue.

Comment: Yes I tried it, but it didn't work.